# Windows CE restores default configuration after restart (Motorola MC3190)

Tags: windows, windows-ce

Good morning, everyone!
I have a problem with Motorola MC3190 hand scanner running on Windows CE.
I've got few of those to make a new program for some kind of warehouse. There is already installed program which have been used by the customers before, so I delete this one and instead I install my new software which I've just made. It is running very well, but when I take out the battery and leave the device for entire night without power supply, it restores the whole configuration, so the old program is back, the wireless configuration is back and... Yeah. The scanner is restored to the configuration which was running when I received it few weeks ago. What I want to do is to set the whole configuration of the scanner so after a long power-off my program and my configuration will be restored.
I truly believe someone knows how to do it. The time is running out, and I believe that the customer will be kind of annoyed when he will change the battery and the program which he bought will be gone. ;-)

Regards,
Jarek

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is the easiest solution I've found. Maybe someone will have similiar problem one day.
I did not found how to save configuration of the wireless/other stuff, but I know that files placed in the **\\Application** and **\\Platform** folders are not deleted after long poweroff. On Motorola MC3190 both folders are accessible from the Windows CE level.

**Edit:
To save the configuration of the wireless, you have to export options and export all profiles (and save them en Application or Platform) (Wireless Applications Menu>Options>Export)

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of the MC3190 Integrator Guide which describes different methods of installing software so you get "persistence".  That is to say to keep the application and settings after a reboot.  You can download a copy from the Motorola support web site at 
https://supportcentral.motorola.com/support/supportcentral/supportcentral.do?id=m1

Answer (score 1):

to maintain your software after cold reboot (because basically this is what you're facing here), you need this tool: StartUpCtl ([Offical Download Link](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=87635&productDetailGUID=f5563b1ca4151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=a0bde8cea8151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD)). In all devices I got it was preinstalled, so I gues it should be the same for your device. This will let you automatically uninstall parasite software in the background during the first boot after restore or reset (or just leaving the device without power for too long) and insall your softwar efrom a cab file. Look for the StartUpCtl folder in \Application. You can find further guidelines in the text files there.

Now for the internet configuration. Standard sofrware lets you export internet configuration in .reg files (both general settings and wifi profiles). If you leave the in \Aplication folder sistem will automatically merge them with system registry (and restore them). If it does not do it automatically, you can restore them on startup using StartUpCtl (i am not sure about the commands, but if i remember it correctly, they can be found in the example in the StartUpClt catalogs).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone by any chance still get's here and is looking for a solution, this PDF should help: http://portal.siriusware.com/docs/kb-pdf/Hardware-related/scanning_2009_july_17_4.pdf

Here's a quick summary:

- Only `\Application` and `\Platform` are persistent, whereby the latter one is reserved for system internal usage.
- During a cold-boot the startup-process `Launch20` looks for `*.reg` (usual `reg` files as you know them) and `*.cpy` files (plain text files where each line should be formatted like `SRC > DEST` - like this example: `\Application\MyApp.exe > \Windows\MyApp.exe`) in the root of your `\Application` and `\Platform` folders and runs them. Order is not guaranteed.
- The startup process is like following:

  1. Registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Init` - ordered by launch id (keys starting with `Launch` followed by a number)
  2. `\Windows\Startup` (order is not guaranteed) - might run together with the `welcome.exe` process
  3. Registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Symbol\Startup\Programs` - invoked by `Startup.exe` which should be registered in the first hook as `Launch70`
  4. `\Application\Startup` - which is the preferred location for installing and launching custom applications. The location of this folder can (but shouldn't) be changed in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Symbol\Startup\Path`. Any application here will not be launched until the Pocket PC Welcome process has completed.